# XCode: after converting the app to Xcode5, NSURL variable is nil at runtime: it worked in the previous version 4.5

Tags: xcode5, nsurl

The following piece of code worked in Xcode 4.5: in a ViewController with an image, a file is loaded from the URL with the description of the image: the name of the file is localized so that the right file will be loaded depending on Italian or English settings.

---

```
NSString *stringaLocalizzata = (NSString *) NSLocalizedString(@"DISCO1_PAGE",nil);
/* Localized file name that contains the object description in english or italian
/* values: 1_locale_en.txt for english
/*         1_locale.txt for italian


NSString *bioLocaleUrl =[[[@"http://" stringByAppendingString:aConstrants.disco_url]stringByAppendingString:aConstrants.doc_dir] //stringByAppendingString:stringaLocalizzata];
       stringByAppendingString:stringaLocalizzata];

NSURL *bioLocaleUrlVersion = [NSURL URLWithString: bioLocaleUrl];
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *bioLocaleWebVersion = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:bioLocaleUrlVersion encoding:1 error:&error];

 _bioLocale.text=bioLocaleWebVersion;
```

---

With Xcode5 it doesn't work animore: at the beginning I thought it was an enconding problem but the real problem is that 
NSURL *bioLocaleUrlVersion = [NSURL URLWithString: bioLocaleUrl]; 
results nil at runtime.

If I change the code in this way:

---

```
NSString *bioLocaleUrl =[[[@"http://" stringByAppendingString:aConstrants.disco_url]stringByAppendingString:aConstrants.doc_dir] //stringByAppendingString:stringaLocalizzata];
       stringByAppendingString:@"1_locale_en.txt"];
```

---

then *bioLocaleUrlVersion will not be nil and everything works.
Of course I can handle this in a different way but I would like to understand which is the problem.
thanks.

Comment: So it looks like `stringaLocalizzata` is breaking the URL.  Have you logged it's value and the full URL string?

Comment: thanks for your reply: of course if I put the full URL string it works: for example http://127.0.0.1/mobile/docs/1_locale_en.txt" that is the local webserver for my developing activities it works.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to create an `NSURL` object with an invalid URL string will return `nil`. Something in your mess of `stringByAppendingString:` calls is resulting in an invalid URL string (see the top of the `NSURL` class reference for full details on what's considered valid.

Without knowing the value of `bioLocaleUrl`, I can't give any more specific advice.

I do strongly recommend using the OS's more suitable routines though. As of iOS 7, `NSURLComponents` is a good bet:

```
NSURLComponents *components = [[NSURLComponents alloc] init];
components.scheme = @"http";
components.host = aConstrants.disco_url;
components.path = [aConstrants.doc_dir stringByAppendingPathComponent:stringaLocalizzata];
```

(based on your code in the question, that seems reasonable)

For older OS releases, I suggest `-[NSURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:]` is your friend.

Comment: Hi, here is the explanation for my URL component: aConstant is an object instance of a class that has values needed by the app and that are stored in a sqllite database:                    aConstant.disco_url stores a fully qualified domain (for privacy reason I cannot write the name here): that could be for example: aConstant.disco_url=@"www.google.it"                                 aConstant.doc_dir=@"/mobile/docs/" and                       stringaLocalizzata = @"1_locale_en.txt".

Comment: What is really strange is that in the previous version of xCode it worked; This is the only problem that my app had when I upgraded to iOS7: so I don't understand why the URL in the previous xCode Version was OK and now is invalid.

Comment: Well I am pretty certain `NSURL` didn't change its validation requirements for iOS 7. If you can't tell us the actual string, you'll have to read through the RFCs yourself to understand why your URL string is invalid

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion: this helped me to find the problem: in my localized file there was a blank space that makes the code failed:    "DISCO1_PAGE='"1_locale_en.txt " instead of DISCO1_PAGE="1_locale_en.txt". The same code still works now on iOS7. I used your suggestion to debug the url and I realized that there was this blanc space. Thanks again!!